Lombok's @Builder - Error java: cannot find symbol
I tried using Lombok on IntelliJ and got the following error
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class com.kelompokhoki.EnergyMonitoringWeb.dto.UserDto


I have checked the annotations and dependencies on the project and am still experiencing the error. I also tried deLombok and still get the same result
Here's my UserDto
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDto {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private List<EnergyUsage> energyUsages;
    private List<TargetUsage> targetUsages;
    private Date createdOn;
}

and this is the problem line
private UserDto mapToUserDto(User user) {
        return UserDto.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .energyUsages(user.getEnergyUsages())
                .targetUsages(user.getTargetUsages())
                .createdOn(user.getCreatedOn())
                .build();
    }


Did you enable annotation processing in Intellij?

@M.Deinum Yes, I already enable the option.

Is this error from Intellij or from maven? If you are using maven make sure you are adding Lombok to the compiler plugin else it won't work on the command line and as you probably imported it as a maven project...

@M.Deinum I genuinely dont know. I already installed the plugin. Before I have this line everything runs normal

You can install whatever you want in Intellij that won't influence what maven does.
